# Pi 5 fan header broke

Tags: cooling

My fan header broke off the board on my new canakit pi 5 max. It's an 8gb system used as a desktop. I have two questions as I consider returning the board.

1. Is the passive cooling perhaps adequate?
2. Is there an aftermarket fan system than I can hook up to the rpio pins?

Note: this is my first pi so I hope I am phrasing my questions correctly. Thanks in advance for effective answers.

Comment: If you're concerned about temperature management, especially in warmer environments or under heavy loads, active cooling (such as a fan) can provide better temperature control.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi 5 can run without a fan for light load tasks, but I think it's not worth the risk long term if you are using it as a general desktop. It's probably best to return the fan kit for a new one.

Is the header on the Pi broken or the header on the fan cable broken?  Both might be repairable with some light soldering if you have the tools handy and don't want to wait for an exchange.

If you want to test things, you can try monitor temp while you are running.

```
watch -n 1 vcgencmd measure_temp
```

The temp should not exceed 85 Deg C

Comment: The SoC is throttled at ~80° C; I don't think there is serious risk of actual damage, just the performance will degrade.  GUI desktop task are usually not very intensive anyway, they are more significant in terms of a memory load.